# Get 'close tab' modal when change route in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I want to show default modal window when user change the route in the react application, adding a condition before triggering the modal.

```js
useEffect(() => {
      if (isMyConditionHappened) {
        history.block(() => {  //block the route changing
          window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => { //want to trigger defailt modal window
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = '';
          })
          return false;
        });
      }
    }
```

Basically the idea is next. If the condition is `true` the user shouldn't be able to navigate to another route, but if he click on another route this shouldn't happen but the default modal window should be triggered, where user should be asked if he remains on the page or to go to another page. I know that in react exist `<Promt/>` component, but i don't need this format, i need only the default modal which is triggered with `beforeload` event. I need this because i listen the situations when user reload the tab or close this, so i need one modal window. 
 How to achieve this? It will help me a lot.

Comment: So you are basically want to prevent people click to a link go the another page make an action?

Comment: @RyanLe, i want to show that modal if user try to access another route in react.

Comment: Which modal and how to trigger that? Could you paste that modal here?

Comment: @RyanLe, this is how the modal looks https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload